# compare objectId with string in mongo query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How do I convert my object id to string so that I can compare it with string in $eq.
mongo version - 4.0

```
db.user.aggregate([{ 
 $lookup:{
     from: "sometable",
     let:{user:["$_id"]},
                         pipeline:[{ 
                                $match: {
                                    $expr: {
                                        $and:[
                                            {
                                                $eq: [ "$userId", "$$user"]
                                              },
                                            {
                                                $gt: [ "$lastBalance", 0]
                                              }
                                            ]
                                           }
                                        }
                            }
                            ],
     as: "response"
  },
}])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [$toString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/),

```
$eq: [ "$userId", {$toString: "$$user"}]
```

Comment: Hi tom.. i tried this. It gives this error --> "errmsg" : "Unsupported conversion from array to string in $convert with no onError value"

Comment: change `user:["$_id"]` to `user:"$_id"` so its not an array

Comment: tried that..but still no output..when i hard code _id instead of $$user i get the results.

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue.  My _id foreignField is of JUUID type. When I do the $toString I get `"Unsupported conversion from binData to string in $convert with no onError value"`

Comment: If it's not supported by `toString` you'll just have to do it in code..

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

`$eq: [ {$toObjectId: "$$userId", "$user"}]`

I don't know why but objectId comparisons are quicker it seems